# Is there a way to write comments between the arguments to a command in a shell script?

Tags: bash, sh

I have a script that calls a command with tons of optional parameters. To keep things readable, it uses line-continuations to write one parameter per line:

```
my_command \
   -flag1 \
   -flag2 \
   -flag3 \
   -flag4
```

My problem now is that I would really like to add some comments next to the flags to describe what they do. Is that possible?

This version I tried doesn't work because `-flag1` and `-flag4` are treated as a separate commands to be run instead of being treated as parameters to `my_command`

```
my_command \
   # These flags are for doing X
   -flag1 \
   -flag2 \
   -flag3 \
   # This last flag is for doing Y
   -flag4
```

Comment: Note that the accepted answer to the question is not very useful, but the others are.